# Add an extra column in select with '*'

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query sql for a data migration job to fetch data and send from mysql-server a to mysql-server b.

Server a has different databases, representing different game channel, and each database has a table `tablex`, they have same table name and same schema:

```
 uid  level
 123    3
 211    5
```

While in server b there is only one table `tablex` to receive tablex of all databases and it has one more column - `channel`

```
channel uid  level
 1      123    3
 1      211    5
 2      355    2
```

I can parse channel number from db name via python but I need to put this constant in the sql and since there are many tables, I cannot fix the columns. So just want to make sure is there any way to do this like:

```
select 1,* from xxx.yyy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding alias and table name

```
select 1 as my_col, yyy.* from xxx.yyy
```

or using string

```
select cast('1'  as  unsigned) , yyy.* from xxx.yyy
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can wrap the query into another `SELECT` and add the columns, e.g.:

```
SELECT A.*, '1'
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM your_table
) A;
```